# EF Core code first db development with explicit collation for each column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have developed a huge database using the code first approach and by huge I mean that I have about a hundred tables which each have around 10 to 20 columns average. Now, I want to define to the migration context to create those tables or columns in accordance with a particular collation and so far Microsoft has not provided anything about this in their online documentation. Although I would like explicit definition for each column, I actually need to set a default collation on the whole db while being able to alter collation for particular columns.

Is there any support for this at all in EF core? Please keep in mind that writing an `ALTER TABLE` statement to tweak collations is not an option here, as I am after an automated solution which would be easy to maintain.

Comment: Did you try this nuget package : http://efcoreshaman.com/

Comment: @ManojChoudhari: Not interested in such third party libraries